# psql export query to csv error

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I'm trying to export the results of my SQL query to a CSV file but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using postgresql version 10.4

```
\copy (select 1,2) To '/test.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

This gives the follwing error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: COPY  ( select 1,2 ) TO STDOUT With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

Running the query by itself works fine. I've also tried removing the brackets.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: the error message I get is permission denied to withe to '/test.csv'  /tmp/test.csv works however.

Comment: @Jasen.Because you(current user) may not have permission to access root user folder. The path "/" specifies root user.

Answer (score 0):

Above query should work fine. Make sure you write the above query in single line and not multi-line.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
\copy (select 1,2) to '/test1.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header quote as '"'
```